# Aggregation not taking place on basis of size paramter passed in ES query

Tags: elasticsearch

My ES query looks like this. I am trying to get average rating for indexes starting from 0 to 9. But ES is taking the average of all the records.

```
GET review/analytics/_search
{
  "_source": "r_id",
  "from": 0,
  "size": 9,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "b_id": [
              236611
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "r_date": {
              "gte": "1970-01-01 05:30:00",
              "lte": "2019-08-13 17:13:17",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "s_type": [
              "aggregation",
              "organic",
              "survey"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "s_id": [
                    392
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "status": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "ba_id": []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "featured": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "r_date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],


   "aggs": {

    "avg_rating": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "rtng": 0
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {

        "rtng": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "rtng"
          }
        }
      }
    },

   "avg_rating1": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "rtng": 0

              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "rtng": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "rtng"
         }
        }
      }
    }


  }
 }
```

The query results shows the doc_count as 43 . whereas i want it to be 9 so that i can calculate the average correctly. I have specified the size above. The result of query seems to be calculated correctly but aggregation result is not proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from` and `size` have no impact on the aggregations. They only define how many documents will be returned in the `hits.hits` array.

Aggregations always run on the whole document set selected by whatever query is in your `query` section.

If you know the IDs of the "first" nine documents, you can add a `terms` query in your query so that only those 9 documents are selected and so that the average rating is only computed on those 9 documents.